# Prevent or Override Text Copy Popup after Touch Press

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch

I'm trying to prevent the default popup (which includes Copy, etc.) from appearing when touch pressing on text in Chrome and other browsers. Specifically I want to replace this popup with my own commands. I still want the text to be selectable via mouse and touch. In other words:

[image]

I can't seem to find any solution that would not completely disable text selection and/or other pointer input.

Handling `contextmenu` with `preventDefault` at the window and span level do not work, nor does handling `touchend`.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit:
It looks like overriding `oncontextmenu` works on Mobile Chrome but not Windows Chrome. Other people report this not working on iOS. Is there any general purpose solution that works on all browsers? Thanks!